# C# Ionic.Zip ZIP file , Multi-level directory appears

Tags: c#, zip

## Solution Directory

```
E:\WebSolution\GenerateFiles
 | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.pdf
 | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.xls
```

---

### Correct

```
E:\WebSolution\GenerateFiles
 | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.pdf
 | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.xls
 | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.zip (Extract) 
                       | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.pdf
                       | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.xls
```

---

### Wrong

```
E:\WebSolution\GenerateFiles
 | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.pdf
 | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.xls
 | NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.zip (Extract) 
                   |WebSolution
                       |--|GenerateFiles
                       |--|--|NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.pdf
                       |--|--|NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.xls
```

======================================================

### Code

```
public void Main(){

   string path=Server.MapPath("~/GenerateFiles"); 
   string zipPackageFileName=System.IO.Path.Combine(path,"NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.zip");

   string[] arrFileName=new string[]{
        System.IO.Path.Combine(path,"NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.pdf"),
    System.IO.Path.Combine(path,"NEW HOTEL-4-64-1379.pdf")
   };   
   
   CompressFilesToZip(arrFileName,zipPackageFileName);
   
}

using Ionic.Zip;
public void CompressFilesToZip(String[] arrFileName, string zipPackageFileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddFiles(arrFileName);
            zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
            zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
            zip.Password = PASSWORD_ATTACHMENT;
            zip.Save(zipPackageFileName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Who can help me ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html), I suspect you want to call

```
zip.AddFiles(arrFileName, false, "");
```

so that the directory hierarchy isn't preserved. It's possible that just

```
zip.AddFiles(arrFileName, "");
```

would work too; it's not entirely clear to me.

(Additionally, I'd strongly recommend that you get rid of the `try`/`catch` block in your method - it's worse than useless, as it *just* loses information. If an exception is thrown within any of the `ZipFile` methods, you'll lose the full stack trace due to the way you're rethrowing the exception.)

Comment: Thank you very much . zip.AddFiles(arrFileName, ""); work fine .I remove try/catch block from my method .